# Equation of the normal to a curve

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, curves

I am struggling to find the equation of the normal to the line:
$$y = \frac{1}{x} - \frac{3}{x^2} - \frac{4}{x^3} + \frac{7}{4}$$ at $(-2,1)$. Any ideas would be appreciated. I believe I need to differentiate, but what do I do after that.

Comment: So you've got a function with a graph, with $(-2,1)$ on it. So you want the normal to the tangent at that point? Why cannot you differentiate? You do know the fomula for functions of the form $x^n$, which also works for $n<0$?

Answer (score 1):

**Tips**:

- Remember $\;\biggl(\dfrac1{x^n}\biggr)'=-\dfrac{n}{x^{n+1}},\;$ so
  $$y'=-\frac2{x^2}+\frac{6}{x^3}+\frac{12}{x^4}. $$
- An equation of the straight line with given slope $m$, passing through a given point $(x_0,y_0)$ is given by the formula
  $$y-y_0=m(x-x_0).$$

The normal at the point with abscissa $-2$ will have slope $m=\dfrac{-1}{y'(-2)}$, and its equation will be
$$y-1=m(x+2).$$